# The handle attribute is must refer to an existing child while implementing SlidingDrawer

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I am trying to implement `SlidingDrawer`. My app is crashing.

**XML FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" >
    </SlidingDrawer>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#C0C0C0"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            layout="@layout/header_history" >
        </include>

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="@android:color/black"
            android:dividerHeight="1.0sp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**LogCat**

```
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demohistory/com.example.demohistory.History}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The handle attribute is must refer to an existing child.
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The handle attribute is must refer to an existing child.
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.widget.SlidingDrawer.onFinishInflate(SlidingDrawer.java:239)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at com.example.demohistory.History.onCreate(History.java:59)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-25 17:40:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The handle attribute is must refer to an existing child.
```

This error is occurred as you have specified

```
android:handle="@+id/handle"
```

in SlidingDrawer's properties. But you have there is no any existing child of Sliding drawer with id 'handle'.

Check [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) for handle property:

> Identifier for the child that represents the drawer's handle.
>
> Must be a reference to another resource, in the form
>   "@[+][package:]type:name" or to a theme attribute in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name".

So you will have to modify your xml file as something like:

```
<SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <ImageView
             android:id="@id/handle"
             android:layout_width="88dip"
             android:layout_height="44dip" />

</SlidingDrawer>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar problem when copying the SlidingDrawer code from the SDK and importing it into my project.  My issue was the namespace of the Layout files.

I fixed the issue by correctly identifying which attributes I was referring like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:dd="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.actionbarslider"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<com.example.actionbarslider.MySlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    dd:content="@+id/mycontent"
    dd:handle="@+id/handle"
    dd:orientation="0" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/exit_light" />

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/mycontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="World"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>       

</com.example.actionbarslider.MySlidingDrawer>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Top Drawer"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note:  I created my own namespace to refer to the styleable attributes, matching the standard "android" namespace.  "xmlns:dd="....".

I did the same thing for the attrs.xml file, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<declare-styleable name="MySlidingDrawer">

    <!-- Identifier for the child that represents the drawer's handle. -->
    <attr name="handle" format="reference" />

    <!-- Identifier for the child that represents the drawer's content. -->
    <attr name="content" format="reference" />

    <!-- Orientation of the SlidingDrawer. -->
    <attr name="orientation" format="integer"/>

    <!-- Extra offset for the handle at the bottom of the SlidingDrawer. -->
    <attr name="bottomOffset" format="dimension"  />

    <!-- Extra offset for the handle at the top of the SlidingDrawer. -->
    <attr name="topOffset" format="dimension"  />

    <!-- Indicates whether the drawer can be opened/closed by a single tap
         on the handle.  (If false, the user must drag or fling, or click
         using the trackball, to open/close the drawer.)  Default is true. -->
    <attr name="allowSingleTap" format="boolean" />

    <!-- Indicates whether the drawer should be opened/closed with an animation when the user clicks the handle. Default is true. -->
    <attr name="animateOnClick" format="boolean" />
</declare-styleable>
```

All working now.

Comment: did you have to then have to call obtainStyledAttributes in your custom view and set the attributes in code? I am having the same issue but my custom SlidingDrawer view inflates in one fragment and not another...

Comment: No, just needed to ensure that the namespace of the attributes that I was using in the resource file was the same as my project's namespace.

Comment: this solved the same exact problem that I had, but don't you have to add the xml namespace in attr.xml too? like the following   <resource> has to be changed to <resources xmlns:dd=""http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.actionbarslider"

Comment: If the attribute is specific to the sliding drawer that's based in your particular package, then yes.  If the attribute belongs to an Android widget, no.  The concept is that the resource tool needs to know which package the variables exist within.